# Are there restrictions on vulgar usernames?

Tags: discussion

Helping with a question on Stack Overflow earlier, I was more than a bit surprised by the vulgar username. Doesn't Stack Exchange have some type of policy or enforcement mechanism to prevent sexist and vulgar usernames?

Here it is:

> [image]

If so, it's not working. If not, is one needed?

That looks really bad on a professional site.

Comment: Just flag it...

Comment: No, that user name is clearly inappropriate. As Alexei said, the appropriate course of action is to flag one of the user's posts for moderator attention and mention the issue with the user name. I've already fixed this one. We don't have an automated process for handling or blocking these. Human moderators review each and every case. So, you (regular community members) are our quality control process. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray What if user does not have any posts? For example, I saw such user in the user list.

Comment: @RocketNikita Flag any post with a link to the user and an explanation of the issue. As described in the dupe: *"If there are no posts, you can flag one of your own posts too; the idea is to drop us a message, it's not about the specific post that was flagged."* - That said you should still only flag ones you come across naturally, don't go hunting for them.

Comment: @Nick Why shouldn't we go hunting for them?

Comment: @Anonymous - Well you can if you want to, but most folks would think it is a waste of their time.  And I don't think there is a way to flag a user's questions or answers (or comments) if they haven't posted any.  That is the approved way to deal with offensive user names.

Comment: There's no point in flagging users who haven't posted anything; no one can see them or their names. If you want to search for offensive language on the Internet, there are *much* better places to do it than the "users" page on Stack Overflow. @Anonymous

Comment: It's a typo, they meant to write "I like Pokemon" of course. Darned autocorrect.